# Auto-update a feature class with Python + .csv?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, feature-class, update

I am hoping to find out how to automatically update a feature class. We have semi-regular updates to an ArcGIS Viewer for Flex website. Looks like a Python script may be the way to go about it (and I know zilch about Python, yikes!).

I am able to get .csv off the website and have been able to import the xy data and create the initial class with that.

Issues: The data from the CSV is in WGS84 and needs to be projected to NAD 1983 StatePlane California III FIPS 0403. Can a script do this as well?

I may be making a mountain out of a mole hill, so in the mean time I can manually edit the information.

The computer has IDLE (Python GUI).

Comment: What does the final product look like to you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

You will need urllib / urllib2 to download the csv. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283799/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-a-url-python) stackoverflow question.)

To load the CSV you will probably want to use [Make XY Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006z000000)

To transform coordinates you will need to [Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) it.

Comment: Good morning, Thank you for your input. I was able to successfully download the csv, import the xy coordinates, and project it in to the appropriate projection.

Comment: Dang.I took to long trying to edit my first comment ... Good morning, Thank you for your input. I was able to successfully download the csv, import the xy coordinates, and project it in to the appropriate projection to create my shapefile. I am wondering if there is a way to write a batch file or script to do this for me so I could run the batch instead of going through each of the steps separately. A sort of auto-update for my shapefile by writing inputs in the batch file so it can go look for any updates to add to my existing shapefile. I apologize if I am not communicating this very well.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. You can have all of the pieces in one .py file, and run that in order to download and create the shapefile again. If you want to update in place rather than create a new one, that would require other tools. I think the easiest option is just create a new one in place rather than trying to de-dupe the data after updating.